# A typecheck errors in deriving wrapper for Linear.V

Tags: haskell, typeclass, haskell-lens, newtype, deriving

I am trying to make a newtype wrapper for the [Linear.V](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.6/docs/Linear-V.html) type and derive useful instances. I was trying this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, 
StandaloneDeriving, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, 
GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, PartialTypeSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}

import Linear.V 
import Control.Lens.At

data Foo = Foo1 | Foo2 deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Attempt 1 - I would think GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving would do, but nope:

```
newtype Bar n = Bar {
  getBar :: V n Foo
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ixed)
```

I get this error:

```
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘f (V n Foo)’
                               with that of ‘f (Bar n)’
        arising from the coercion of the method ‘ix’
          from type ‘Index (V n Foo)
                     -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (V n Foo) (IxValue (V n Foo))’
            to type ‘Index (Bar n)
                     -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (Bar n) (IxValue (Bar n))’
      NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘f’ have;
        we must assume that the role is nominal
    • When deriving the instance for (Ixed (Bar n))
```

I have made attempt 2 using standalone deriving like this:

```
newtype Bar n = Bar {
  getBar :: V n Foo
} deriving (Show, Eq)
type instance Index (Bar n) = Int
type instance IxValue (Bar n) = Foo

deriving instance Ixed (V n Foo) => Ixed (Bar n)
```

But then I got a different error:

```
• Couldn't match representation of type ‘f1 (V n Foo)’
                           with that of ‘f1 (Bar n)’
    arising from a use of ‘GHC.Prim.coerce’
  NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘f1’ have;
    we must assume that the role is nominal
• In the expression:
    GHC.Prim.coerce
      @(Index (V n Foo)
        -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (V n Foo) (IxValue (V n Foo)))
      @(Index (Bar n)
        -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (Bar n) (IxValue (Bar n)))
      ix
  In an equation for ‘ix’:
      ix
        = GHC.Prim.coerce
            @(Index (V n Foo)
              -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (V n Foo) (IxValue (V n Foo)))
            @(Index (Bar n)
              -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (Bar n) (IxValue (Bar n)))
            ix
  When typechecking the code for ‘ix’
    in a derived instance for ‘Ixed (Bar n)’:
    To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
  In the instance declaration for ‘Ixed (Bar n)’
• Relevant bindings include
    ix :: Index (Bar n)
          -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (Bar n) (IxValue (Bar n))
      (bound at a.hs:12:1)
```

I am unsure why either of the errors actually happens. Could this be done somehow? I am not so experienced with the advanced type level features and so far I was also unable to actually write this particular instance definition manually, so I would consider that a solution as well. But I would prefer to use the `deriving` mechanism somehow, since it seems more reusable.

EDIT: I have tried this manual instance decalaration:

```
type instance Index (Bar n) = Int
type instance IxValue (Bar n) = Foo

instance Ixed (Bar n) where
  ix i f (Bar v) = ix i f v
```

But that yield the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘V n Foo’ with ‘Bar n’
  Expected type: f (Bar n)
    Actual type: f (V n Foo)
• In the expression: ix i f v
  In an equation for ‘ix’: ix i f (Bar v) = ix i f v
  In the instance declaration for ‘Ixed (Bar n)’
• Relevant bindings include
    v :: V n Foo (bound at a.hs:14:15)
    f :: IxValue (Bar n) -> f (IxValue (Bar n)) (bound at a.hs:14:8)
    i :: Index (Bar n) (bound at a.hs:14:6)
    ix :: Index (Bar n)
          -> Control.Lens.Type.Traversal' (Bar n) (IxValue (Bar n))
      (bound at a.hs:14:3)
```

Which seems to me like that the compiler can't figure out that the `Index` of both `V n Foo` and `Bar n` is `Int`. But I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The remaining problem is transforming the `ix` [traversal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Traversal) for the underlying `V n Foo`, which ultimately returns a function `V n Foo -> f (V n Foo)`, into an `ix` traversal for the wrapper type `Bar n`, which should ultimately return a function `Bar n -> f (Bar n)`. We have to "unpack" the definition of [`Traversal'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Traversal-39-) to know this.

In your code, `ix i f v` has type `f (V n Foo)`, so it is enough to `fmap` with the `Bar` constructor:

```
type instance Index (Bar n) = Int
type instance IxValue (Bar n) = Foo

instance Ixed (Bar n) where
  ix i f (Bar v) = fmap Bar (ix i f v)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is acceptable solution for me. I suppose it has zero runtime overhead, right? Is there still any hope to do this using the `deriving` mechanism somehow?

Comment: @user1747134 It is a newtype, so I guess it won't have overhead. I don't think there's a way to use `deriving` though.